# Error accessing to SVN: E175002: SSL handshake failed

Tags: svn

I'm getting this error today to access to mine SVN repository:
svn: E175002: SSL handshake failed: 'Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.'

can you please advice what and where I should check to fix it?

I cannot commit nothing.

thanks

Comment: Which SVN client are you using ? Which version ? On which platform ?

Comment: I'm using from Eclipse Keplero, SVN Browser is working fine from windows

Comment: Eclipse Kepler is 5 years old, and the coresponding Subversion plugin (do you use Subversive or Subclipe) will have no support for TLS. You have to upgrade Eclipse to a newer version, then use a more current plugin version, and the problem will go away.